# $C_0(U)+C_0(V)=C_0(U\cup V)$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and let $U,V$ be open subsets of $X$. Then $C_0(U)$ and $C_0(V)$ are ideals in $C_0(X)$. Sum of ideals in a $C^*$-algebra is again an ideal (without even taking the closure), so $C_0(U)+C_0(V)$ is an ideal in $C_0(X)$ and therefore corresponds to some open subset $W\subseteq X$, i.e. $C_0(U)+C_0(V)=C_0(W)$.
I think that $W=U\cup V$.

It is clear that $C_0(U)+C_0(V)\subseteq C_0(U\cup V)$ as an ideal. However, I couldn't show that this inclusion map is surjective.

I have tried to consider the character space of $C_0(U)+C_0(V)$. It corresponds to kernels of irreducible representations of the algebea. Then one can first consider the irredicible representations that vanish on the ideal $C_0(U)$ (and correspond to irreps that factor through the quotient space) and those which doesn't vanish on the ideal and correspond to irreps of the ideal.

But, I would like to show it more directly, that is, to take a fumction in $C_0(U\cup V)$ and approximate it with sums of functions from $C_0(U), C_0(V)$.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why would  ideals be thus related to open sets?

Comment: [The compact case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956278/characterization-of-ideals-of-algebra-of-continuous-functions-on-a-compact-space)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603012/when-is-c-0uc-0v-c-0u-cup-v-true?rq=1). This answers my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\in C_0(U\cup V)$. Then $f$ has compact support $A\subseteq U\cup V$.
Let $A_0=A\setminus V$ and $A_1=A\setminus U$. Then $A_0$ and $A_1$
are compact and disjoint. By Urysohn's lemma, there is a continuous
$f:X\to[0,1]$ which is zero on $A_0$ and $1$ on $A_1$. Then $fh$ is zero
on $A_0$, and has compact support in $V$. Likewise $f(1-h)$ has compact
support in $U$. Then $f=fh+f(1-h)\in C_0(U)+C_0(V)$.

Comment: Thank you! Elegant proof! I think that $A$, the support of $f$ is not necessarily compact (for example, there are $f\in C_(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. However, it is enough to take $A$ to be a compact set s.t. outside $A$, $||f||<\epsilon$ and it would be okay. Thanks again!